The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00__sveltekit/server'
When migrating to old SvelteKit project I am getting this error when running npm run dev.
How to solve?
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string, Uint8Array, or URL without null bytes. Received '\x00__sveltekit/server'
    at open (node:internal/fs/promises:605:10)
    at Object.readFile (node:internal/fs/promises:1085:20)
    at loadAndTransform (file:///Users/moo/code/frentek/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:54957:34)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/moo/code/frentek/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:55940:10)

npm run preview works fine.

Make sure you do not have an old instance of npm run dev allocating the port 5173.
